# Firebase syncObject is showing redundant error in my Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am building an app for a client who has, as one of their data sets a master list of all their members.  I have the data coming in from Firebase and everything runs peachy, but it's not that DRY I am now realizing.  I would like to use some of the data from the membership set in other views within the site.  I copied the code listed below into other controllers that I need to have access to it and although everything works, my IDE (RubyMine) shows the 'syncObject' as redundant.

So, my question is, if there's a way to code it better and dryer to be used in other views?  Thank you for your time.

```
   .controller( 'MembershipCtrl', function MembershipCtrl( $scope, $firebase ) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://myid.firebaseio.com/members");
        var sync = $firebase(ref);
        var syncObject = sync.$asArray();
        $scope.members = syncObject;
 });
```